# Shared instance with dictionary (c++)

Tags: c++, dictionary

I'm C++ newbie here. I'm trying to implement something. My goal is simple:

1. A shared instance which can be easily accessed in different scopes.
2. This shared instance has a dictionary instance variable (map) to store key-value pair data.
3. We can add a new key-value pair or get the value for a key via the public accessor.

Here is my header:

```
// .h
using namespace std;

class Person;
typedef map<string, Person> DictForPeople;

class Company {
    Company();
    void setValueForKey(string key, Person value);
    Person valueForKey(string key);
private:
    DictForPeople _dictForPeople;
};

class Person {
public:
    Person();
    void setName(string name);
    string name();
private:
    string _name;  // !!!: raise error here
};
```

and the implementation (.cpp):

```
// .cpp
Company::Company(){

}
void Company::setValueForKey(string key, Person value){
    _dictForPeople[key] = value;
}
Person Company::valueForKey(string key){
    return _dictForPeople[key];
}
Person::Person(){

}
void Person::setName(string name){
    _name = name;
}
string Person::name(){
    return _name;
}
```

I'm trying to use [**singleton pattern**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern), but it raises a lot of compilation errors. How to correctly declare a shared instance with accessors for string/map?

---

**UPDATE 1:**

The above code raises an error: ***Implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >'***

The environment is **Xcode 6**/**Mac OS X 10.10** with LLVM/Clang. I'm trying using C++ instead of Objective-C for some reasons.

---

**UPDATE 2:**

My implementation with Singleton Pattern is the following ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern)):

```
// .h
using namespace std;

class Person;
typedef map<string, Person> DictForPeople;

class Company {
    static Company& getInstance() {  // For Singleton Pattern
        static Company instance;
        return instance;
    }

    void setValueForKey(string key, Person value);
    Person valueForKey(string key);
private:
    Company() {};  // For Singleton Pattern
    Company(Company const&);  // For Singleton Pattern
    void operator=(Company const&);  // For Singleton Pattern

    DictForPeople _dictForPeople;
};

class Person {
public:
    Person();
    void setName(string name);
    string name();
private:
    string _name;  // !!!: raise error here
};
```

This change raises more errors:

1. ***Field has incomplete type 'Person'***: this could be fixed by moving the class declaration `Person` above the class declaration `Company`.
2. Other errors are the same message introduced before (***Implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >'***) but in different places. The C++ file `utility`  LLVM

   ```
   template <class _T1, class _T2>
   struct _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS_ONLY pair
   {
       typedef _T1 first_type;
       typedef _T2 second_type;

       _T1 first;     // <<<-- raise the error here
       _T2 second;

       // pair(const pair&) = default;
       // pair(pair&&) = default;

       _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR pair() : first(), second() {}
   ```

---

**Update 3:**

I forgot to mention that the above code is embedded in `extern "C" {...}` block.

Comment: *"I'm trying to use singleton pattern, but it raises a lot of compilation errors"* - the code you've posted isn't even trying to use the singleton pattern as provided in the question you've linked to... where's your current code attempting the singleton?

Answer (score 0):

You code seems fine to me.

Did you included `string` and `map` in your header file? If yes, please also provide the compilation `error's`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I add the updates to my question.